# How do I view the forks of a fork on Github?

Tags: github, fork, github-api

How can I view the forks that originated FROM another fork? The project I'm looking at has a ton of forks to the point where Github can't even show all of them already but I wanted to see the forks from a certain fork, if that makes sense.

For example:

```
Original Project
 '-> Fork 1
 '-> Fork 2
      '-> Fork 2a
      '-> Fork 2b
      '-> Fork 2c
 '-> Fork 3
```

I want to see the projects that were forked from Fork 2 so that means fork 2a, 2b, 2c, etc.

Is ther an extension or website or software or whatever that I can use to view this information?

Comment: Go to the GitHub page. Click on 'Insignts' then 'Network'. It will show you all of the branches of a project including the ones forked by other users as well as the commits made on each branch and how branches interact. It won't be perfect and it can take a while to load for massive repositories with lots of commits, but it might be able to give you a general idea of what is going on.

Comment: @Locke any reason not to make that an answer?

Answer (score 25):

### View Forks

Head to the project and click **Insights**, then **Forks**. This will show you a paginated table of all the forks.

[image: Arrow pointing between Insights and Forks]

You can filter the table by period and repository type and then sort based on stars, recent updates, open issues and open pull requests.

There is a "Switch to tree view" button in the upper right-hand corner which may be useful to visualise the forks, but not all forks will be shown if there are too many.

---

### View Fork Network Graph

From the **Insights** tab, you can see the last 100 recently pushed forks by clicking the **Network** tab. This graph can take several seconds to load, depending on how many forks of the project there are.

The network graph has keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>H</kbd> to scroll all the way **left**
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>L</kbd> to scroll all the way **right**
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd> to scroll all the way **up**
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>J</kbd> to scroll all the way **down**

You can see more shortcuts [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-github/keyboard-shortcuts#network-graph).

Comment: "Switch to tree view" was the thing I was missing, it's the only way to match the fork count on the to with the number of forked line displayed.